# cachefilesd - how to ensure file is copied from local cache?

Tags: centos7, nfs, cache

I have setup `cachefilesd` and to check if it is correct I verified following:

- `cachefilesd` service is running
- NFS storage is mounted with `-o fsc` and able to see `FSC` set to `yes` in `/proc/fs/nfsfs/volumes`
- when a file is copied from NFS I see new content added in `/var/cache/fscache` (this is setup in `/etc/cachefilesd.conf`

Now when I first copy a 4 Mb from the NFS and the time taken as per the `time` command comes something around `400-450 millsecs`, then if I copy same file again the time is reduced to `50-60 millisecs`. The reduced time made me happy that local cache is working as expected.

But when I turned off `cachefilesd` service and remounted the storage without `-o fsc` option, I still see the same behavior i.e the second time copying still takes the same amount of time. I believe when the `cachefilesd` was on the copy from local cache should have been more faster.

I checked a few sites where it was mentioned that there could be caching enabled on the NFS server itself and maybe that is why second time copy is faster even when `cachefilesd` was off.

So to test if the second time copying is from local cache I thought of introducing latency using the `tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 400ms`. (I ensure `cachefilesd` is on and NFS storage is mounted with `-o fsc`). Now with this I see the first time copy is taking much more time as expected for eg. `8-10 secs` and to the surprise the second time copying take around `800 millisecs` to `1 sec` which is still high if the file is being copied from local cache. This behavior again matches when `cachefilesd` is off.

The questions:

- Why does second time copy is taking so much time when `cachefilesd` is on and when latency is introduced ?
- How to find if the file is copied from local cache ?

Any sort of hints will be very helpful.

Can anyone provide any sort of information ?